# How to dynamically generate VBox like a div in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to automatically generate VBox according to the number of result. For example, if the number of result is 3 then i want to automatically generate 3 VBox.
I have written the following code below by following this example: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/javafx-20-layout-panes-hbox-and-vbox.html

but it doesnt work:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane apne;

@FXML
private VBox vbxOuter;

@FXML
private VBox vbxInner;


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    apne = new AnchorPane();
    vbxOuter = new VBox();

    getnewer(apne, vbxOuter, vbxInner);

}


public void getnewer(AnchorPane apne, VBox vbxtrue, VBox vbxmain){



    for(int i = 0; i<3 ; i++){

        vbxInner = new VBox(i+1);
        vbxOuter.getChildren().add(vbxInner);

    }

    apne.getChildren().addAll(vbxOuter);

}
```

apne is a anchor pane containing vbxOuter. I want vbxOuter to get automatically generated according to the number of result. vbxinner will contain buttons and labels. what should i do?

Comment: Remove these two lines: `apne = new AnchorPane(); vbxOuter = new VBox();`. You are re-creating the injected nodes, so actually what is visible on the GUI is the not node that you are working on in the code.

Comment: I did what you said and now i am getting this error: " Children: duplicate children added: parent = AnchorPane[id=apne] "

Comment: Nevermind. i added this line of code " vbxOuter = new VBox(i+1);" in my loop and the error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

`apne` and `vbxOuter` should already exist and be available to your methods if you made them using FXML. All you have to do is populate `vbxOuter` in your method.

```
@FXML private AnchorPane apne;
@FXML private VBox vbxOuter;


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    apne.getChildren().add(vbxOuter);

    int numberOfInnerVBoxes = 3;
    getnewer(numberOfInnerVBoxes);
}


public void getnewer(int num){
    for(int i = 0; i<num ; i++){
        vbxOuter.getChildren().add(new VBox(i+1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey i tried your code and i am getting this error: " Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = AnchorPane[id=apne] ". Do you know off any solution to this?

Comment: nevermind. I added this line of code "vbxOuter = new VBox(i+1); " in the loop and it doesnt show me the error anymore